# Resource Timing API - Is there a way to retrieve the HTTP request method?

Tags: javascript, http, request, resource-timing-api

Using the resource timing api, `window.performance.getEntries()` returns a list of performance entries with timing information. This sort of information is shown in browser network debuggers. See here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Resource_Timing_API/Using_the_Resource_Timing_API

Using `window.performance.getEntries()` or some other method on the `performance` object / Resource Timing API, is there a way to get the HTTP method (Get, Post, Put, Delete, Patch)? I do not see a way to get the HTTP method on the `PerformanceResourceTiming` interface for example: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformanceResourceTiming